# Regex not matching for extracting IIS site ID

Tags: regex, logging, iis

I've written a regex that extracts the site ID of the folder of IIS.

The regex is as following:

`[^W3SVC\\]+(?=\\[^\\]+\\?$)`

This works as expected but not when the site ID is ending with an 3. See the following examples:

```
Match 11: C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC11\u_ex210724.log
Match 44: C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC44\u_ex210724.log
No match: C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC63\u_ex210725.log
```

I don't understand this. What is wrong here with the regex why this does not match?

Comment: What programming language (or regex flavor) are you using? You probably want something like `(?<=W3SVC)\d+(?=\\)`.

Comment: Note that the reason for not returning a match with the third line is because you're telling it not to match '3' (i.e., in `[^W3SVC\\]`). If "W3SVC" is not a fixed string, you might want to [edit] the question to clarify the rules.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to write this regex

```
W3SVC(\d+)
```

This will match the site ID into group 1.

Since I know how IIS logfile paths typically look like, and yours are as expected, there is no reason to make it any more complicated than it is.

But if you positively *have to*, you can use a look-behind:

```
(?<=W3SVC)\d+
```

which gets the site ID itself as the entire match.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex contains a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), `[^...]`. This character class matches any chars other than those specified in the class.

You used the class in a wrong way in an attempt to exclude a part of a string from a match. You need a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) here:

```js
(?<=\\W3SVC)[^\\]+(?=\\[^\\]+\\?$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QC0A5s/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=\\W3SVC)` - a location that is immediately preceded with `\W3SVC`
- `[^\\]+` - one or more chars other than `\`
- `(?=\\[^\\]+\\?$)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `\`, one or more chars other than `\` and then an optional `\` followed with end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. This was exactly what I needed.

I need to have the site ID only so the following regex is working as needed:

```
(?<=W3SVC)\d+
```

Thank you all for the feedback.